# Ignore multiple directories in git hook

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I want to ignore any `dist` and `node_modules` directories in my git commit hook. I've tried this:

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | find . -path ./node_modules -prune -o -path './**/dist -prune -o -name '*.js'
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't seem like the find is accepting the files found from the git diff...

If I run:

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM
```

I correctly get the staged files:

```
./dist/some-file.js
```

And if I run:

```
find . -path ./node_modules -prune -o -path './**/dist' -prune -o -name '*.js' -print
```

I correctly get a list of files that don't include any that are in `dist` or `node_modules` directories.

How can I combine these do that my git hook doesn't pick up staged files in dist directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` doesn't process its standard input, so it can't be used after `|`

grep can be used instead

```
| grep -v '/dist/' | grep -v '/node_modules/'
```

or using one grep process

```
| grep -Ev '/dist/|/node_modules/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. How do I use this along with looking for .js files? Another pipe ? | grep -Ev '/dist/|/node_modules/' | grep ‘.js$’ ?

Comment: yes, `grep -v` is an exclude filter, `grep` without  `-v` include filter, `-E` is for extended regexp, see also grep --help

Comment: I have multiple dist folders which are sometimes nested. I’ve tried /**/dist/|/node_modules/ but that just gives me “repititon operator operand invalid “

Comment: It’s ok I think I need /*dist/|node_modules/

Comment: grep operates only over intput stream (strings) the pattern is a regexp pattern not a glob `/dist/` matches any path which contains `/dist/`, see grep documentation and regular expressions for more information